# Нет подключения к MySQL из java кода написанного в IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Установил MySQL на ноутбук, вставил несколько разных кодов, написанных на java, в IDEA, попытался подключится к MySQL -  не подключается.

Установлена библиотека mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.
Пробовал в MySQL заблокировать root и создал другого пользователя - всё равно не подключается.

Но сама IDEA подключается к БД без проблем, подключившись я могу смотреть таблицы, а также их редактировать, удалять и добавлять строки, а вот через код не хочет.

Помогите решить проблему.

При попытке подключения выдаёт:

```
-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------

Зарегистрирован драйвер MySQL JDBC!

    Sun Aug 26 10:36:29 VLAT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    
    Ошибка соединения! Проверить выходную консоль
    
    java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 9 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Connection.JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:26)
    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 9 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:128)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2236)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2260)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1314)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:963)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 0с
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Ошибка гласит:**

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 9 (çèìà)' is
>   unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure
>   either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.

В ней сказано, что указанный часовой пояс не определён, и Вас просят указать конкретный часовой пояс, если Вы собираетесь его использовать.

Для этого нужно явно указать `serverTimezone` в строке подключения, например:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

**Warning гласит:**

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

Там говориться, что не рекомендуется установление соединения без проверки подлиности сертификата и что начиная  с версии 5.5.45+ установления безопасного соединения по умолчанию является обязательным и для его отключения необходимо указать свойство `useSSL=false` в строке соединения. В итоге строка будет выглядеть вот так вот:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
```

Либо указать драйверу, что необходимо установить безопасное соединение, **но проверять подлинность сертификата не нужно**. Для этого необходимо установить параметр `useSSL=true`, что говорит о необходимости установления безопасного соединения и указать второй параметр `verifyServerCertificate=false` для отключения проверки подлинности.

Строка соединения будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
```

Comment: Теперь пишет так:    Mon Aug 27 10:19:13 VLAT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: @sema207, по поводу ворнинга все написано в тексте ошибки, добавьте `useSSL=false` также в строку соединения

Comment: @sema207, обновил ответ.

Comment: Ура пишет: -------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Зарегистрирован драйвер MySQL JDBC!
Вы сделали это, теперь управляйте своей базой данных!

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Михаил Ребров большое спасибо за помощь, я две недели мучился (((

Comment: @sema207, не за что. Благодарить тут принято отметкой верного ответа и плюсиками ))

Comment: @sema207,посмотрите: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Михаил Ребров хочу нажать стрелочку вверх чтобы поставить вам голос + но скрипт почему то возвращает назад на 0-ль автоматически. Как быть?

Comment: @sema207, возможно для голосования Вам еще не хватает репутации. Вы сможете голосовать при достижении репутации >= 15 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @sema207, но Вы всегда можете отметить вопрос верным, после этого и репутации прибавится

Comment: @sema207, удачи Вам. Если появятся вопросы - заходите :-)