# Неизвестная ошибка и не понимаю с чем связано

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-boot

```
    "C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\jbr\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56935:C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\target\classes;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.persistence.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.transaction.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.jms.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.ejb.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.resource.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.1\HikariCP-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.6.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.1\byte-buddy-1.10.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.0\classmate-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mustache\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-mustache-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\samskivert\jmustache\1.15\jmustache-1.15.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.0\jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.0\jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.0\jackson-core-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.18\mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar com.example.ApiConnect.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2019-10-29 13:18:23.159  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ApiConnect.Application       : Starting Application on msk-dev-017 with PID 4876 (C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\target\classes started by vladislav.gilenko in C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis)
2019-10-29 13:18:23.159  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ApiConnect.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-29 13:18:23.213  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2019-10-29 13:18:23.213  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-29 13:18:23.213  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-29 13:18:23.722  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-29 13:18:23.773  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-10-29 13:18:23.975  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-29 13:18:24.166  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-29 13:18:24.172  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-29 13:18:24.172  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-10-29 13:18:24.268  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-29 13:18:24.268  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1055 ms
2019-10-29 13:18:24.378  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2019-10-29 13:18:24.421  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.6.Final}
2019-10-29 13:18:24.513  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-10-29 13:18:24.572  INFO 4876 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-10-29 13:18:24.726 ERROR 4876 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ApiConnect.Application.main(Application.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Мой код:

Message

```
package com.example.ApiConnect.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, String tag) {
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

MessageRepo

```
package com.example.ApiConnect.repos;

import com.example.ApiConnect.domain.Message;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface MessageRepo extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
}
```

Application

```
package com.example.ApiConnect;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

GreetingController

```
package com.example.ApiConnect;

import com.example.ApiConnect.domain.Message;
import com.example.ApiConnect.repos.MessageRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(
            @RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name,
            Map<String, Object> model
    ) {
        model.put("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Message message = new Message(text, tag);

        messageRepo.save(message);

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }
}
```

greeting.mustache

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello, {{name}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.mustache

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Тэг">
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <div>Список сообщений</div>
    {{#messages}}
        <div>
            <b>{{id}}</b>
            <span>{{text}}</span>
            <i>{{tag}}</i>
        </div>
    {{/messages}}
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.36:3306/NameBase?true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pas
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath/>

    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->


</parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>

    <artifactId>ApiConnect</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ApiConnect</name>

    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>

</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>

</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>

</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Проблема в версиях библиотек.

Comment: Я с ними уже несколько дней бьюсь, не знаю сколько вариантов перепробовал. Что не так? С какими библиотеками тут проблемы.

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске. Как вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: :D Извините, забыл добавить файлик,  обновил топик, pom.xml

Comment: При запуске в класспас попадает `C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.persistence.jar`. Откуда оно берется? Во вкладке мавена прорефреште проект чтобы идея перечитала депенденси. И удалите все что было добавлено вручную.

Comment: Сейчас полностью переписал pom.xml. Обновлённая версия. Сейчас добавлю в топик. Там ошибки до сих пор выводятся почему-то. Не подскажете как рефрешить проект. Если просто пкм на pom.xml -> maven ->reimport, то сделал и ничего не дало.

Comment: [MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1.33 - Time Zone Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27276523/312041)?

Comment: Посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873760/201445

Comment: @gil9red Давайте я выберу ваш вариант правильным. Сделайте ответ на этот вопрос. Остальные ошибки для других топиков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, часовой пояс не распознан или представляет собой больше одного часового пояса.

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'MSK' is
>   unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure
>   either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.

Поэтому, нужно явно параметром `serverTimezone` указать часовой пояс в строке подключения к базе данных, например:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC

[Ответ на аналогичную проблему.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873760/201445)